# Image is all grey after averaging

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2

redArry = []
greenArry = []
blueArry = []


def chunk(n, lst):
    n = min(n, len(lst) - 1)
    return [lst[i:i + n] for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1)]


def average(group):
chunkCtrl = 0

for im in group:
    B = im[:, :, 0]
    G = im[:, :, 1]
    R = im[:, :, 2]

    redArry.append(R)
    greenArry.append(G)
    blueArry.append(B)
    chunkCtrl +=1

    if chunkCtrl == 2 :
        for x in range(im.shape[0]):
            for y in range(im.shape[1]):
                chunkCtrl = 0
                sumRed = 0
                sumGreen = 0
                sumBlue = 0

                for i in range(2):
                    redImage = redArry[i]
                    sumRed += redImage[x, y]
                    print redImage

                    greenImage = greenArry[i]
                    sumGreen += greenImage[x, y]
                    print greenImage

                    blueImage = blueArry[i]
                    sumBlue += blueImage[x, y]
                    print blueImage

                    sumRed = sumRed / 2.0
                    sumGreen = sumGreen / 2.0
                    sumBlue = sumBlue / 2.0

                image = cv2.merge((sumRed , sumGreen , sumBlue))
                return image






arrayOfFrames = []

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('myVideo.mp4')
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        arrayOfFrames.append(frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('p'):
            cv2.waitKey(0)
    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


groupedFrames = chunk(2 , arrayOfFrames)

for group in groupedFrames:    
    averagedImage = average(group)    
    cv2.imshow("Result" , averagedImage)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am trying to average a video with open CV and python. 
the idea is i take frame 1 and 2 average them and return the new image.

Algorithm explation
split movie into array of frames. 
divide that array into over lapping chunks. 
for each image in chunk 
split the image into 3 channels 
get the sum of each channel 
make a new image with the averaged sum 
show the image

Comment: Will that code even run in the state as posted? Good chunk of it appears misaligned, which is a bit of a show stopper in Python.

Comment: yeah runs fine locally , i think something happened during the upload
Will try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your average(group) function, rewritten:

```
def average(group):
    chunkCtrl = 0
    new_image = np.zeros(np.shape(group[0]))

    for im in group:
        chunkCtrl += 1
        B = im[:, :, 0]
        G = im[:, :, 1]
        R = im[:, :, 2]

        for x in range(im.shape[0]):
            for y in range(im.shape[1]):
                new_image[x,y,0] += B[x,y]
                new_image[x,y,1] += G[x,y]
                new_image[x,y,2] += R[x,y]

                if chunkCtrl == 2:
                    new_image[x,y,0] = new_image[x,y,0]/2.0
                    new_image[x,y,1] = new_image[x,y,1]/2.0
                    new_image[x,y,2] = new_image[x,y,2]/2.0

        # this is not necessary if your chunks are always 2 images, which they seem to be
        if chunkCtrl == 2:
            return new_image

    return new_image
```

I can't really explain what was wrong with your code as I'm not sure the indentations in the question reflect your actual code, but some things to point out:

- redArry, blueArry, and greenArry are declared as global when they don't need to be. Initialize them as empty at the start of each call to average(group) to avoid errors.
- From the indentation in the question, it seems like you are returning the merged image before actually traversing the entire image array.
- Notice how sumRed, sumBlue, and sumGreen are initialized to 0 at every pixel (inside both loops for x..., and for y...). Since you loop over the individual pixels of an image before going to the next, you're never actually summing up the pixels from each image.

I recommend using the function scopes to your advantage as a way to know where a variable should be initialized, where it can be updated, and where it shouldn't be used. This can save you a lot of debugging time!

EDIT: OpenCV is great and has many useful image processing tools. A good one is this: [Image Blending](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19)

Comment: Hi , The above is now returning an image that i can work with ,although the output is not what i expected at all.

Comment: I haven't actually tested this code. This [page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html) could help you (Image Blending section)

Comment: Is this the right approach to remove noise in the video?

Comment: It is one approach. Read [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html)

Comment: Why so much code? Since the same thing is being done to all the pixels, this could be reduced to few vectorized array operations, cutting the code size to a fraction and most likely improving performance by at least an order of magnitude.

Comment: @DanMašek absolutely correct. I tried keeping his code structure, but as I mentioned in my edit there is already an openCV function which does just that

Answer (score 2):

Performing per-element addition or division of numpy arrays by manually iterating over all the elements in Python is a **terrible pessimization**.

Taking advantage of the [vectorized arithmetic operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations) that numpy provides, we can rewrite the function from the answer by @ma22 in the following manner:

```
def average_fast(group):
    if len(group) == 1:
        return np.float64(group[0])

    new_image = np.zeros(np.shape(group[0]))

    for im in group[:2]:
        new_image += im

    return new_image / 2.0
```

Same result, ~60% less code (less to maintain and IMHO easier to grok what it does). Not only that -- measuring the two approaches on a set of 1024x1024 RGB images, we can see that this approach is almost 200x faster (25 ms compared to almost 5 seconds).